# Trying to insert 'Tag search' into my android application

Tags: android, search, tags

I'm trying to make a tag search function for my Android application, but was unable to find any documentation related to tag search...

My scenario is, if I type a word and type space or comma after that, it becomes a single tag object. (Just like the one that we use in stackoverflow)

Could you help me out? Thx in advance.

Comment: I am thinking about using a textwatcher and detecting a comma/space and change it into tag .....(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: Ok I'll try that out. Maybe there is no library for custom tag search? Thx for your help